# rviz crashes when adding display

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have deleted my ~/.rviz directory and rviz loads fine, but as soon as I click 'add' to add a display, the program seg faults.

Any suggestions? It was working a week or two ago just fine... :/

If I open one of my saved settings files, it loads fine but I can't add anything.

Hydro on U13.04

```
$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1381326753.836165659]: rviz version 1.10.6
[ INFO] [1381326753.836304863]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1381326754.842062938]: OpenGl version: 3.3 (GLSL 3.3).
[rospack] Warning: no such package media_export
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88901/rviz-crashes-when-adding-display/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-10-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-10-08**:
What's the rviz version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
sudo apt-get purge ros-hydro-*
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
```

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-09-22**:
Thanks to this answer I was able to fix [this issue](http://answers.ros.org/question/159606/hydro-rviz-crashes-groovy-not-glibc-detected-corrupted-double-linked-list/?answer=193260#post-id-193260). I think adding `$ sudo apt-get autoremove` makes it more perfect.